Unable to export loges to a file as exporter using config.yaml in Docker Desktop container in Windows
cannot start pipelines: open ./store.txt: permission denied. collector server run finished with error
We want to export logs using Docker desktop container  to the file and store it into local machine.
we tried with setting up exporter with the file path in config.yaml file but it's not working.
Code:
exporters:
debug:
verbosity: detailed
file:
path: ./Store.txt

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

As described in the File exporter's documentation:

The official opentelemetry-collector-contrib container does not have a writable filesystem by default since it's built on the scratch layer. As such, you will need to create a writable directory for the path, potentially by mounting writable volumes or creating a custom image.

One way to solve your issue is to configure the File exporter to write to a directory that is mounted to the host:
exporters:
  file:
    path: /otelcol-output/store.txt

And then mount the /otelcol-output/ directory to the host when running the Otelcol container like this:
docker run --rm -v 'C:\Users\andrz\otelcol-config.yaml:/etc/otelcol/config.yaml' -v 'C:\Users\andrz\otelcol-output\:/otelcol-output/' otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib:0.98.0 --config /etc/otelcol/config.yaml 

After that, you should have the data available in the file C:\Users\andrz\otelcol-output\store.txt on your host machine.
